# utf-8 plus question marks

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a site that displays user input by decoding it to unicode using utf-8. However, user input can include binary data, which is obviously not always able to be 'decoded' by utf-8.

I'm using Python, and I get an error saying:

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: unexpected code byte. You passed in '\xbf\xcd...

Is there a standard efficient way to convert those undecodable characters into question marks?

It would be most helpful if the answer uses Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
inputstring.decode("utf8", "replace")
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) for reference

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
str.decode('utf8','ignore')
```

which should drop invalid bytes rather than raising exception

Comment: or Joril's method.... basically look at the options for [decode()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)